# asp.net mvc3 and multi-level navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, navigation, url-routing

i am writing new asp.net mvc application and i have question about creating multi-level navigation system.

For example i have web with main navigation (Cpu --- Gpu ---- Ram)

and sub-navigation with (intel,amd --- ati,nvidia --- DDR2,DD3)

Well, my first implementation is here :

```
public class NavigationItem
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Controller { get; set; }
    public virtual string Action { get; set; }
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual string Section { get; set; }
}


public class NavigationController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public NavigationController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public ActionResult MainMenu()
    {
        return View(_unitOfWork.NavigationItems.Where(x => x.Section == null).ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult SectionMenu()
    {


        return View(_unitOfWork.NavigationItems.Where(x => x.Section == "// name of section").ToLis());
    }
}
```

And finally my layout page is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main-menu">
  @{Html.RenderAction("MainMenu", "Navigation");}
 </div>

 <div class="section-menu">
  @{Html.RenderAction("SectionMenu", "Navigation");}
 </div>

    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

With this implementation i have problem how i handle in SectionMenu with MainMenu is active, because i want generate SectionMenu depends on MainMenu and highlight them.

One workaround of witch i think is handle url(controller) in SectionMenu.
For example :

```
    if (RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Administration")
    {
        // Generate section menu for Administration main menu
    }
```

I dont like this solution because i work with "magic string" values and i havent only one controller per one MainMenu.

How implement this solution?

Thanks for advice

Comment: Any updates on how you accomplished this? I just wrote almost exactly this same code trying to do the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I use  ViewBag feature. Not clean, but works

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to get deeper into MVC's routing system. It doesn't look very straightforward in the beginning, but this is probably the most important area of the entire MVC. Sometimes though you can easily get confused especially if you have many routes defined in Global.asax. There is a project called Route debugger, it helps. I don't remember the link. Try to google it... If you can't find it I'll send the link later...

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes route debugger is great stuff link is here : http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx.

Btw yes you are right, i have many routes defined in Global.asax :/